# ORM-like library for C

Tags: c, orm

I have been looking for a ORM library for C(I was thinking about something like ActiveRecord on Ruby) and I can't find any. I was wondering if someone has ever heard of one and could let me know. Thanks in advance.

Eduardo Sorribas

Answer (score 1):

Although you can write Object-Oriented C, most people thinking in terms of "objects" tend to use C++.  Trying to map an **object**-relational mapper into C would be difficult and odd to use, especially when you don't have a clear concept of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) directly in the language.

Most people wanting the abstraction provided by an ORM would probably be using C++ (or some other higher level language).

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a difficult search, because "ORM" implies "Object" and C is not an object oriented language.

I think it's unlikely that anyone has implemented an ORM for a non-OOP language - it would just be too difficult to make fit/work.

Comment: You can still implement an OOP design in C, but you can't get the same encapsulation or polymorphism.